# Different returns in different responses & to return a part of the response in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have a login API that returns me following **JSON** If the user's credentials match.

```
{
  "user": { 
        "ok": true,
        "data": {...}
   },
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9"
}
```

If the user's credentials do not match. I get.

```
{
    "user": {
        "ok": false
    },
    "message": "Oops! Wrong password."
}
```

I have this Copper API code

```dart
import ...

part 'authApiServices.chopper.dart';

@ChopperApi(baseUrl: "/auth")
  abstract class AuthApiServices extends ChopperService {
    @Post(path: "/login", headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    Future<Response<User>> login(
      @Body() Map<String, String> body,
    );

   static AuthApiServices create() {
    final client = ChopperClient(
      baseUrl: 'https://URL/api',
      services: [
         _$AuthApiServices(),
       ],
      converter: AuthConverter(),
        );

     return _$AuthApiServices(client);
  }
}
```

Now depending upon the `user.ok` I want my app to respond.

> Note: The API will always send response status **200**.

If the login is successful I only want to store/return the `user.data` not the whole response also store the token in `shared preferences`.
So I have created a `User` model class using `app.quicktype.io`

Now, I know that I have to play with this `converter: AuthConverter()` and add the whole logic here.

So this is my `AuthConverter` class.

```dart
import 'package:chopper/chopper.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:venue_monk/models/user_model.dart';


class AuthConverter extends JsonConverter {
  @override
  Response<BodyType> convertResponse<BodyType, InnerType>(Response response) {
    return  decodeJson(response) as Response<BodyType>;
  }

  @override
  Response<User> decodeJson(Response response) {
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

    if(responseJson['user']['ok']) {
      return response.replace(
        body: responseJson['user']['data'],
      );
    }

  }
}
```

Doing this I get an error

> Cannot convert from `Response<Dyanmic>` to `Response<User>`

I also need help with returning diff things w.r.t the `user.ok` value.

I know I'm asking a lot. But if anyone could help as I'm very much new to Flutter.

Thank You!.

Comment: You cannot mutate the existing Response. You have to create a new one (or change the return type)

Comment: @RémiRousselet I have the return type as User but it not changing. I think I have some issue with `decodeJson` but now sure what.

Comment: The thing is, you're returning a Response. Why not return User directly, or a custom class?

Comment: @RémiRousselet but inside i have body as User model.